# Application onTime update

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue on this code, bassicaly its running only one time when it is tiggered, what could be wrong?

```
Sub test()
xTim791 = "11:10:05"
If Minute(Now) < 1 Then
    TimeToRun = TimeValue(Hour(Now) & ":01:05")
End If
Debug.Print TimeToRun
If Format(sTim, "hh:nn:ss") = Format(xTim791, "hh:nn:ss") Then
    Debug.Print "I have done for " + xTim791
M1_Update
Prev_Update
End If
Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the name of your variable , `TimeToRun` or `sTim`? Using `Option Explicit` is highly recommended.

Comment: TimeToRun @A.S.H. I'm gonna have a look on that function, thx!

Comment: Your code may break before reaching the line `Application.OnTime...`. Or it may be triggered but you're not observing it because all the if conditions are not met, so its prints nothing out.

Comment: I'll try to double check it, even if I don't have vba skills, thx @A.S.H!